# My List View is not getting populated

Tags: android

I am trying to parse json data and to display that on my custom list view.

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ListView list;
 ArrayList<listview> array_list = new ArrayList<listview>();

 class listview {
  String description;

  public listview(String description) {
   this.description = description;
  }
 }
 
 class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
  
  

  public MyAdapter(Context context) {   
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return array_list.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
   return array_list.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
  }

  @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
   TextView description = (TextView) view
     .findViewById(R.id.description);
   listview list = array_list.get(position);
   description.setText(list.description);
   return view;
  }
 }

 class getJson_data extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

   Get_data data = new Get_data();
   String output = "";
   try {
    output = data.get_info();

    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(output);
    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jobject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
     JSONObject product = jobject.getJSONObject("product");
     String description = product.getString("desc");
     array_list.add(new listview(description));
    }

   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
     .permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  }
  new getJson_data().execute();
  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
  list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
 }

 
}
```

Below u can find my custom layout listview.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_info"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon_circle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_info"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_info"
        android:src="@drawable/verified_circle_check_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_info"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is an helper class (it's working fine) that extracts the json data, converts it to a string and returns it back to the doInBackground method.

```html
Get_data data = new Get_data();
String output = "";
try {
 output = data.get_info();
```

Here is the json data that I got from the helper class method

```html
[
   {
       "@type": "item",
       "ID": 1036,
       "product": {
           "active": true,
           "categories": [],
           "desc": "thubnil image icon testing",
           "gtins": [],
           "id": 443,
           "image": "",
           "modelNumber": "thubnil im",
           "name": "test image"
       }
   },
   {
       "@type": "item",
       "ID": 781,
       "product": {
           "active": true,
           "categories": [],
           "desc": "cars",
           "gtins": [],
           "id": 46,
           "image": "",
           "modelNumber": "car1234",
           "name": "Cars"
       }
   },
   {
       "@type": "item",
       "ID": 783,
       "product": {
           "active": true,
           "categories": [],
           "desc": "cars",
           "gtins": [],
           "id": 46,
           "image": "",
           "modelNumber": "car1234",
           "name": "Cars"
       }
   }
]
```

But nothing appears in my listview... Where did I go wrong? Please any suggestions on how to this would help me a lot. Thanks in advance

Comment: get object of MyAdapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute() of Async task.or you can set adapter in onPostExecute method

Comment: Is this code of mine correct.?
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(output);
    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jobject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
     JSONObject product = jobject.getJSONObject("product");
     String description = product.getString("desc");
     array_list.add(new listview(description));
    }

Comment: you are not updating your view on `onPostExecute` please consult this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: How to update my view. I am unable to understand

Comment: Well I think I will put my comment as answer so you vote it, so any one will get the right aswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update your list view, you need to write code to update the list view in `onPostExecute()`. Please consult this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)